# Jquery Newline doesnot display on message popup

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have code which displays a confirmation popup.

```
 string message = "Do you want to set activity to Inactive? " ;
 message += "The predefined settings will be reset for all the users using this Activity.";
 SetToInactiveCheckBox.Attributes["onclick"] = "if($('input[id*=SetToInactiveCheckBox]:checkbox:checked').length > 0 ) return confirm('"+ message +"');";
```

I want the two lines to be printed in separate lines.
I tried in a following ways

```
string message = "Do you want to set activity to Inactive? \n" ;
 string message = "Do you want to set activity to Inactive? '\r\n'" ;
 string message = "Do you want to set activity to Inactive? '<br/>'" ;
```

How too display the messages in separate lines. I am using IE8.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear, qre you using `alert`, the `jQuery` popup box or something else?

Comment: @drew_w `return confirm('"+ message +"');`

Comment: Perhaps impossible without modifying the code that displays the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\n or \r\n.
```

If that does not work then use

```
\\r\\n
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<br />
```

instead of

```
'<br />'
```

This worked for me.